can i search for multiple regions in a map created with geojson?
hello i'm pretty new to programming and by boss asked me to create a cutsom map of great britain, divided by the various post codes regions.
for this i used a premade geojson map (https://github.com/missinglink/uk-postcode-polygons/tree/master/geojson) and now i want to enter multiple search request in my search bar (i.g im searching for "AB10,AB11") and have those shown on the map highlighted by different colours.
At this time im just able to search for a singular region and have it highlighted by a red circle, but i want it to highlight the whole region in a different colour
if you have a solution for either one of those problems (get the search result highlighted or be able to search for multiple regions simultaneously) that would be awesome :)
heres my code:
combined_geojson = merge_geojson([AB, AL, B, BA, BB, BD, BH, BL, BN, BR, BS, CA, CB, CF, CH, CM, CO, CR, CT, CV, CW, DA, DD, DE, DG, DH, DL, DN, DT, DY, E, EC, EH, EN, EX, FK, FY, G, GL, GU, HA, HD, HG, HP, HR, HS, HU, HX, IG, IP, IV, KA, KT, KW, KY, L, LA, LD, LE, LL, LN, LS, LU, M, ME, MK, ML, N, NP, NR, NE, NG, NN, NW, OL, OX, PA, PE, PH, PL, PO, PR, RG, RH, RM, S, SA, SE, SG, SK, SL, SM, SN, SO, SP, SR, SS, ST, SW, SY, TA, TD, TF, TN, TQ, TR, TS, TW, UB, W, WA, WC, WD, WF, WN, WR, WS, WV, YO, ZE])

map = folium.Map(location=[51.5074, -0.1278], zoom_start=6)

# Create GeoJSON layer
geojson_layer = folium.GeoJson(combined_geojson).add_to(map)

# Determine search label
properties = combined_geojson['features'][0]['properties']
search_label = next(iter(properties.keys())) if properties else None
search_label = search_label if search_label else 'name'

# Define a variable to store the search term
search_term = None

# Custom JavaScript callback function to update search term
js_callback = """
function(e) {
    var input = document.querySelector('.leaflet-search-wrap > input');
    input.addEventListener('input', function() {
        window.search_term = input.value.toLowerCase();
    });
}
"""

# Create search control
search = plugins.Search(geojson_layer, search_label=search_label, search_zoom=14)
search.add_to(map)
map.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element('<style>.leaflet-control-search .search-tooltip{display:none}</style>'))  # Hide tooltip
map.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element('<style>.leaflet-control-search{text-align: left !important;}</style>'))  # Align text left

# Add JavaScript callback to update search term
map.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element('<script>{}</script>'.format(js_callback)))

# Highlight function
def highlight_function(feature):
    global search_term
    if search_term and search_term in feature['properties'][search_label].lower():
        return {'fillColor': 'yellow', 'color': 'blue', 'fillOpacity': 0.5}  # Ändere die Füllfarbe in Gelb, wenn ein Treffer gefunden wird
    else:
        return {'fillColor': 'white', 'color': 'blue', 'fillOpacity': 0}  # Setze die Füllfarbe auf transparent, wenn kein Treffer gefunden wird

# Add GeoJSON layer with highlight function
folium.GeoJson(combined_geojson, style_function=highlight_function, name='highlight').add_to(map)

# Save the map
map.save("maptest.html")


